# Migrating my data to a new MIUI Android phone

Tags: xiaomi, data-transfer, device-migration, xiaomi-mi9

I'm switching from a Xiaomi RedMi 3S phone (Android 6.0.1) to a MI 9 SE which I just got. None of the phones are rooted. I don't have a Google account, nor a "Xiaomi account" -  but like any phone user, I have my contacts, history of phone calls, SMS messages, and conversation on various apps, and more generally a bunch of app data.

I would like to transfer, or back-up-and-then-"restore", as much of this data as possible; with as little work as possible. Specifically, I'm hoping to be able to back up multiple things at once, or with one tool / method, rather than looking for app-specific solutions for each and every app. But - I don't want to involve Google or Xiaomi in any of this.

What would you suggest?

Note:

- I'm perfectly willing to do command-line work or adapt a script if that helps.
- If a reasonable solution requires rooting one or both of the phones, it's a viable answer, but please explain why that's necessary (as, obviously, I've refrained from doing that so far).

Comment: I don't think you are gonna get something better than what's already discussed: [\[backup\]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup?tab=Votes), [\[restore\]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restore?tab=Votes). The second highly voted question here on Android SE: [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Saying "you should do a backup, then a restore", with those links, is a decent answer to this question AFAIAC.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Also, the answer you linked to says: "This solution will not back up and restore contact, SMS or calendar information"

Comment: @einpoklum The answer you got is because of the restrictions you made. Backup on Android requires special permissions, hence on an unrooted device only system apps can do a "real backup". Therefore the only "all-in-one" solution in your case is a backup app from Xiaomi like the "Mi Mover app" (this app seems to work cloud-less, local data transfer only).

Comment: @Robert: So, you're saying that if I am willing to root my older device, I could do something more effective? Or do I need root on both devices?

Comment: @einpoklum Unfortunately apps that don't allow backup (e.g. via adb) can't be restored without root. Thus for a full backup both devices have to be rooted. But I am not sure how rooted backup apps handle the AndroidKeyStore. This is a central service that stores cryptographic keys on behalf of the apps. For some apps the only really working backup is the app-specific backup/restore provided by the apps itself.

Comment: @Robert: So, is it "worth it" to root my device just for this purpose? Or - how many is "some"?

Comment: @einpoklum In my opinion not. But the question is irrelevant in any way because in the process of rooting the device all user data is deleted for security reasons. Hence if your old phone is not rooted yet a backup using root is just impossible. And which apps can't be fully restored using root+backup depends on the apps you use. AFAIK a popular app that uses AndroidKeyStore is e.g. Signal. Other are mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/machiav3lli/oandbackupx/issues/96